# How to convert a 1D array to a 2D array?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am writing a code to solve the 2D heat equation. I have **nx** points along the x dimension and **ny** points along the y dimension. (nx and ny are user inputs). The solution comes out as an array of shape (nx*ny,). But naturally, I want to plot the solution as a 2D array. So I tried to assign the values of the result to another 2D array like this:

```
# A is a (nx*ny, nx*ny) sparse square matrix of csc format. b is a (nx*ny,) NumPy array.
y = sp.linalg.bicgstab(A, b)    # shape of y is (nx*ny,)
solution = np.zeros((nx, ny))
for i in range(0, ny):
    for j in range(0, nx):
        solution[i, j] = y[i + nx * j]
```

But this raises the error:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Numerical Practice/FDM-2D Heat Equation-No Source.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Numerical Practice/FDM-2D Heat Equation-No Source.py", line 77, in main
    solution[i, j] = y[i + nx * j]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Where am I going wrong and what can I do to fix this? I have checked the initial result (y) by directly printing it. y comes out correctly. The error occurs after the solution is done.

P.S. If I use the function `sp.linalg.spsolve` instead of `sp.linalg.bicgstab`, It works fine. But I am exploring sparse iterative solvers so I wish to use `sp.linalg.bicgstab`.

Comment: why not `solution = y.reshape((nx, ny))`?

Comment: @norok2 I am not familiar of the inner workings of the reshape function. But I wanted the assignment of values to follow a particular pattern where elements get assigned row-wise. I mean I want the first nx elements of y to go to the first row of the solution matrix, second nx elements to the second row, and so on. So I opted to go this route.

Comment: Yes, that's what reshape does, without having to make a second copy in memory or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code.

The one that triggers the error you observe derives from the return value of `scipy.linalg.bicgstab()` being a `tuple` and not the NumPy array you are expecting.

The other issue is that you try to access an object of shape `(nx, ny)` with indices `i, j` ranging from `0` to `ny` and `nx` respectively. Therefore, unless you have `nx == ny` the code from above would exceed the array boundaries at some point.

Finally, all this is accomplished with explicit looping. However, NumPy offers better tools to obtain what you are after, and specifically `np.reshape()`.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

nx = 800
ny = 1200

y = np.random.randint(0, 100, nx * ny)


def reshape_loops(y):
    solution = np.zeros((nx, ny))
    for i in range(0, nx):
        for j in range(0, ny):
            solution[i, j] = y[i + nx * j]
    return solution


def reshape_np(y):
    return np.reshape(y.copy(), (nx, ny), order='F')


print(np.allclose(reshape_loops(y), reshape_np(y)))
# True


%timeit reshape_loops(y)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 319 ms per loop
%timeit reshape_np(y)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 ms per loop
```

with the vectorized approach being some ~250x faster.

Answer (score 1):

I dug around in the official documentation. It turns out that all the sparse iterative solvers return two things: the solution and the convergence information. If it is just written as `y = sp.linalg.bicgstab(A, b)`, y becomes a tuple of shape (2,) where the first element is the solution and the second element is the convergence information. I fixed it by doing `y, exit_code = sp.linalg.bicgstab(A, b)`. Now it works fine

Comment: @norok2 Yes, you are correct. It doesn't work as I just found out. I have now chosen to go for the reshape function and it works well. Thanks!